Cubic Concatenation
Challenge
Given three non-negative integers \$a, b\$ and \$c\$, decide if the sum of their cubes is equal to the concatenation of those numbers, aka:
$$
a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3} = a^\frown b ^\frown c
$$
Test cases
Truthy
(1,5,3) // 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153
(2,2,13)
(4,0,7)
(10,0,0)
(10,0,1)
(22,18,59)
(98,28,27)
(166,500,333)
(828,538,472)

Falsy
(1,2,3) // 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 = 32 != 123
(4,5,6)
(6,0,0)
(166,500,334)
(200,0,200)

You can assume there are no leading zeroes.
This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins.

Could you define concentration in the question please

@Simd Sorry, did you make a typo?

From your test cases I assume leading zeroes don't count?

@Jitse well, I didn't include any test cases with leading zeroes because it may cause issues with, for example, "001" being different from "1" and I just wanted people to focus on writing shortest code without getting into edge cases too much.

Yes, I meant concatenation.

But doesn't 0 have a leading zero?

Python 3, 36 bytes
lambda*I:eval(3*"%d"%I+3*"-%d**3"%I)

Try it online!
eval golf of @Jitse's answer who generously declined to include it in their post.
Returns zero for True and nonzero integer for False.

R, 30 29 bytes
Edit: -1 byte thanks to @Kirill L..
\(x)x^2%*%x==Reduce(paste0,x)

Attempt This Online!

Save a byte with dot product

Jelly,  5  4 bytes
-1 thanks to Unrelated String! (*3S {cube then sum} -> ḋ² {dot-product with squared values}.)
ḋ²⁼V

A monadic Link that accepts a list of non-negative integers (with or without any leading zeros*) and yields 1 if the list concatenates to the sum of the cubes of its elements or 0 if not.
Try it online! Or see the test-suite.
How?
ḋ²⁼V - Link: list, A = [a, b, c]
 ²   - square {A} -> [a², b², c²]
ḋ    - {A} dot-product {that} -> a³+b³+c³
   V - evaluate {A} as Jelly code -> concatenated integer *
  ⁼  - {SumOfCubes} equals {that}?

* Leading zeros produce a side effect of printing zeros before yielding the result.

*3S -> ḋ² for 4

Very nice golf @UnrelatedString, I often use the dot-product too so should really have thought of this one. Thank you!

Python 3, 44 bytes
lambda x:sum(map(pow,x,[3]*3))-int(3*'%d'%x)

Try it online!
-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan
-2 bytes thanks to xnor
Returns truthy (nonzero integers) for False cases and falsey (zero integers) for True cases.
Python 3, 45 bytes
lambda a,b,c:a**3+b**3+c**3-int(f'{a}{b}{c}')

Try it online!

You can flip truthy and falsey with == -> -.

36: lambda*I:eval(3*"%d"%I+3*"-%d**3"%I)

@Albert.Lang amazing! I'll leave it to you to submit it as a separate answer

Quite suprised by the syntax of map(3 .__rpow__,x) with the space separation. Any link to explain this?

@david With the space there, the dot is parsed as an attribute accessor instead of a decimal separator. More here.

Shorter to do map(pow,x,[3]*3) in the second answer

Haskell, 33 bytes
(==).show.sum.map(^3)<*>(>>=show)

Try it online!

sum.map(^3) is the sum of the cubes
show.sum.map(^3) is stringifies the sum
(>>=show) is concatMap show, i.e. concatenetes the numbers
<*> feeds the input to both arguments


I tried non-pointfree and it also came to 33 bytes: Try it online!

Uiua, 17 14 12 chars
-3 chars thanks to Chunes by replacing fork with on
-2 chars thanks to OVS because I missed the existance of a power operator
=/+ⁿ3⟜⍜°⋕/⍚⊂

Pad Link

14 without the function pack: =/+××..⟜⍜°⋕/⍚⊂

I think ××.. is just ⁿ3

This =/+ⁿ3⟜⍜°⋕/◇⊂ is what I had came up with when this was first posted to the Sandbox but I didn't see the challenge is already posted... I'm too slow and I had prep time!

@noodleperson Nice! I needed a lot of help to get to the same result

APL (Dyalog Unicode), 16 bytes
+.*∘3=∘⍎∘∊⍕¨

Try it online!
+.*∘3 sum of cubes
=∘⍎∘∊ equal to the execution of the enlisted (flattened)
⍕¨ stringification of each

JavaScript (Node.js), 32 bytes
(a,b,c)=>a**3+b**3+c**3==[a]+b+c

Try it online!
Nothing to say.

Concatenating a number to a list coerces them to string? Obvious in hindsight :)

Vyxal, 6 bytes
ṅ?3e∑=

Try it Online!
    ∑  # Sum
  3e   # of cubes
 ?     # of input
     = # Is equal to
ṅ      # Concatenation of input?


Julia, 26 24 23 bytes
-n="$(n'n.^2)"==join(n)

Attempt This Online!
Thanks to ovs for -2 and further -1 by Ashlin Harris.

Your TIO link for the 0.6 version doesn't actually test that function and I can't get it to work? Anyway, I think n'*n.^2 should work in both julia versions if you pass input as arrays instead of tuples

@ovs Oops, my bad. Anyway, the older version is no longer needed as it becomes the same length. Thanks!

Julia supports implicit multiplication, so you don't need the * operator.

Brachylog, 7 bytes
^₃ᵐ+~c?

Try it online!
Explanation
^₃ᵐ        Map cube on the input list
   +       The sum of these cubes…
    ~c?    …can be deconcatenated into the original input list


Google Sheets, 31 bytes
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A^3)=--JOIN(,A:A) 


K (ngn/k), 17 bytes
{(,/$x)~$+/x*x*x}

Try it online!

Bash, 28
Sometimes the simple solution is best:
(($1**3+$2**3+$3**3^$1$2$3))

This script takes a list as command-line parameters as input.   e.g. ./cubeconcat.sh 1 5 3.  It returns a shell exit code: 1 for True, 0 for False.
Try it online!

Previous, overcomplicated solution:
Bash, 37
(($(eval printf %s +\$[$1**3] ^ $1)))

This script takes a single quoted brace-enclosed, comma-separated list as input.   e.g. ./cubeconcat.sh "{1,5,3}".  It returns a shell exit code: 1 for True, 0 for False.
Try it online!

Excel, 23 Bytes
An anonymous workbook function that takes input from a vertical array at A1# and outputs to the calling cell
--(A1&A2&A3)=SUM(A1#^3)

Previous Version, 24 bytes
A slightly more elegant solution that uses the Concat builtin
--CONCAT(A1#)=SUM(A1#^3)

Sample Output
For the input array ={1;5;3} outputs the following


Desmos, 81 67 bytes
-14 bytes thanks to @emanresu A due to the fact that I didn't realize that it was always guaranteed to be exactly 3 numerical inputs. I was originally solving for an arbitrary amount of numerical inputs.
c(x,y)=x10^{floor(log(y+0^y))+1}+y
f(x,y,z)=c(c(x,y),z)-x^3-y^3-z^3

Returns 0 for truthy and a non-zero integer for falsey.
Try It On Desmos!
Try It On Desmos! - Prettified

60: c(x,y)=x*10^{ceil(log y)}+y[NEWLINE]f(x,y,z)=c(x,c(y,z))-x^3-y^3-z^3 (I'm not that experienced with Desmos golf, this can probably be a little less)

Actually disregard that it doesn't play nice with zeros, there's probably a trick somewhere though

c(x,y)=x*10^{floor(log(y+0^y))+1}+y[NEWLINE]f(x,y,z)=c(c(x,y),z)-x^3-y^3-z^3 seems to work for 68, since leading zeros won't happen

@emanresuA Wait what??? You can assume there's only three numbers inputted?????

Man they gotta make three bolded, I just skipped right over that word.

MathGolf, 5 bytes
‼yⁿΣ=

Try it online.
Explanation:
‼     # Apply the next two operands separately on the (implicit) input-triplet:
 y    #  Join them together
  ⁿ   #  Take the cube of each
   Σ  # Sum the triplet of cubes
    = # Check if the two lists are the same
      # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)


ARBLE, 21 bytes
a^3+b^3+c^3-(a..b..c)

0 for truthy, non-zero for falsey.
Try it online!
Run all tests!

Perl 5 -MList::Util=sum -ap, 27 bytes
$_=y/ //dr==sum map$_**3,@F

Try it online!

Red, 41 bytes
func[a][(sum a * a * a)= do rejoin to[]a]

Try it online!
Takes input as a vector of three numbers. Vectors support arithmetic with multiple values at once, but not powers.
Explanation
func[a][         ; start function taking argument a
(sum a * a * a)  ; sum of cubes
=                ; does it equal...
to[]a            ; input converted to regular list
rejoin           ; concatenated to string
do               ; evaluated (converted to integer)
]                ; end function


Japt, 5 bytes
x³¥U¬

Try it here
x³¥U¬     :Implicit input of array U
x         :Sum of
 ³        :  Cubes
  ¥       :Loosely equal to
   U¬     :  U joined to a string


Stack control 1.1, 6 characters
:³+⇆◡=

Explanation
:  - duplicates original array
³  - cubes every array element
+  - sum of array elements
⇆  - swap to another array
◡  - reversed concatenates values from array
=  - check if values are equals


Javascript (V8), 40 bytes
a=>a.reduce((x,y)=>x+y**3,0)==a.join('')

where a is number[], so it should work for any number of arguments.
Try it online!
33 bytes
Thanks @Neil and @tsh for the shorter version!
a=>a.map(x=>s-=x**3,s=a.join``)|s


I think a.join\`` works.

By default, [tag:decision-problem] on this site allow truthy vs falsy output, and swap meaning of true and false is allowed. So you could use - to replace your ==. Combine with Neil's idea. It could be stripped into 35 bytes: `a=>a.reduce((x,y)=>x-y**3,a.join``)`

And switch to map could save two more bytes: `a=>a.map(x=>s-=x**3,s=a.join``)|s`

@tsh I forgot that arrow functions do not have their own scope. That's clever!

APL+WIN, 17 bytes
Prompts for integers.
(⍎∊⍕¨s)=+/(s←⎕)*3

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

J, 15 bytes
;(=1#.^&3)&:".>

Try it online!
Takes input as list of boxed strings.

Charcoal, 9 bytes
⁼Ｉ⪫θωΣＸθ³

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as an array and outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. - if the sum of cubes equals the concatenation, nothing if not. Explanation:
   θ        Input array
  ⪫         Joined by
    ω       Predefined variable empty string
 Ｉ          Cast to integer
⁼           Equals
       θ    Input array
      Ｘ     Vectorised raised to power
        ³   Literal integer `3`
     Σ      Take the sum
            Implicitly print


Ruby, 30 bytes
->a{a.sum{|x|x**3}.to_s==a*''}

Try it online!

I have almost the same, but two bytes can be golfed by replacing |x|x with _1
Attempt This Online!

05AB1E, 6 bytes
3mOIJQ

Try it online or verify all test cases.
The 3m could alternatively be ** or n* for the same byte-count; or the order could be swapped to JI3mOQ as well:
Try it online.
Explanation:
3m      # Take the cube of each value in the (implicit) input-triplet
  O     # Sum those together
   I    # Push the input-triplet again
    J   # Join them together
     Q  # Check if the two are the same
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)


Go, 108 bytes
import."fmt"
func f(a,b,c int)bool{n:=0
Sscanf(Sprintf("%d%d%d",a,b,c),"%d",&n)
return a*a*a+b*b*b+c*c*c==n}

Attempt This Online!

Windows Batch, 43 bytes
cmd/cset/a%1*%1*%1+%2*%2*%2+%3*%3*%3-%1%2%3

Prints 0 for truthy, <>0 for falsy.
Sorry, no TIO available; save as C:\Temp\cg274690.cmd or whatever.cmd, run from cmd.exe or PowerShell:
C:\Temp\cg274690.cmd 1 5 3
Ungolfed:
cmd.exe /c set /a %1 * %1 * %1 + %2 * %2 * %2 + %3 * %3 * %3 - %1%2%3

This starts another instance of cmd.exe, as using set /a inside a batch script requires an assignment, which would then have to be echoed out, for a total of 49 bytes (using LF as EOL):
set/ax=%1*%1*%1+%2*%2*%2+%3*%3*%3-%1%2%3
echo %x%

set /a used interactively inside a cmd prompt (or passed with /c) prints the result directly.

Lua, 38 bytes
x,y,z=...print(x^3+y^3+z^3==0|x..y..z)

Try it online!

Kotlin 52 Bytes
{it.map{it*it*it}.sum()-it.joinToString("").toInt()}

Accepts a List<Int> and outputs zero for true and a non-zero integer for false.
Try it online

Setanta, 84 66 bytes
gniomh(a,b,c){toradh a*a*a+b*b*b+c*c*c==go_uimh(nasc@[a,b,c](""))}

try-setanta.ie link

Arturo, 31 bytes
$->a->=do join a∑map a=>[&^3]

Try it!
Explanation
$->a->        ; a function taking a list named a
=             ; are the following two values equal?
do join a     ; concatenation of input as a number
∑             ; and sum of...
map a=>[&^3]  ; inputs cubed


AWK, 24 21 bytes
$1$2$3~$1^3+$2^3+$3^3

Try it online!
Prints the digits if true, or returns nothing.

C++, 186 165 146 bytes
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;int main(){int a,b,c;cin>>a>>b>>c;cout<<(a*a*a+b*b*b+c*c*c==stoi(to_string(a)+to_string(b)+to_string(c)));}

(-16 thanks to Mousetail) (-19 thanks to Blue)
Try it online!

that's fair, didn't see that. give me a second

@emanresuA fixed

You can save 16 bytes with cout<<(d==stoi(x));

You can get rid of d altogether! cout<<(a*a*a+b*b*b+c*c*c==stoi(x));

@Blue thanks! good point :P

141 bytes

Java (JDK), 120 bytes
t->t.stream().mapToInt(x->x*x*x).sum()==Integer.parseInt(t.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()))

Try it online!
I'm not sure if the import of java.util.List needs to be counted. The predicate takes a List and some old advice says that all the types for lambdas need to be included, with any imports, but in JShell it is imported by default and in JDK 23 (which is currently only a preview edition) you also get it for free in a Java program that is all in one file (you can even skip declaring a class or having a full public-static-void-main), but TIO doesn't support JShell or recent versions of Java.

Retina, 54 bytes
,(\d+),(\d+)
$1$2,$.(***_$2*$2*$2*_$`*$`*$`*
^(.+),\1$

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation:
,(\d+),(\d+)

Match the first number in $`, the second number in $1 and the third number in $2.
$1$2,$.(***_$2*$2*$2*_$`*$`*$`*

Concatenate the input numbers, then compute the sum of the cube of $1 (implicitly because it's the first number in the match), the cube of $2 and the cube of $`. (Retina 1 will do this calculation using arbitrary-precision integers as it knows it will be converting the result back to decimal.)
^(.+),\1$

Check that the two results are the same.

JavaScript (Node.js), 31 bytes
(x,y,z)=>[x]+y+z-x**3-y**3-z**3

Try it online!
A boring trivial solution is short...

You could save 2 bytes by taking the arguments as strings.

Bash, 33 bytes
[ $1$2$3 = $[$1**3+$2**3+$3**3] ]

Try it online!
The script returns a shell exit code: 1 for True, 0 for False.

PowerShell Core, 45 bytes
-join$args-(($args|%{"$_*"*3+1})-join'+'|iex)

Try it online!
Takes 3 integers as parameters
Returns \$0\$ for true, otherwise false=

MATLAB, 41 bytes
f=@(x)sum(x.^3)==str2num(sprintf('%d',x))

An @-function that accepts input as column vector.
>> f([828;538;472])
ans =
  logical
  1
>> f([200;0;200])
ans =
  logical
  0


Welcome to the site and nice first answer! You may skip f= from your bytecount. Also for the demonstration purposes and to have the bytes counted you can use TIO website. MATLAB isn't available there, but you try GNU Octave . See this example.

Factor, 46 45 bytes
[ 4 dupn v* v. swap "%d%d%d"vsprintf dec> = ]

Try it online!
Explanation
[                 ! start function
4 dupn            ! put 4 total copies of input list on stack
v*                ! multiply top two
v.                ! dot product w/ third
swap              ! put input on top
"%d%d%d"vsprintf  ! concat all three to string
dec>              ! to number
=                 ! check equality
]                 ! end function


gnuplot, 33 bytes
f(a,b,c)=a**3+b**3+c**3=="".a.b.c

Try it online!
A function that inputs 3 integer values and outputs 1 if their sum of cubes is equal to  the concatenation of those numbers, otherwise the output is 0.

Pyth, 9 bytes
qsjkQsm**

Try it online!
First time golfing in Pyth, so this might be not optimal.
Explanation:
sm** calculates the sum of the cubes;
jkQ joins the list elements into a string and s converts the result to a number;
q: are the values equal?

Clojure, 56 bytes
#(=(seq(str(apply +(for[i %](* i i i)))))(mapcat str %))

TIO. This was surprisingly painless, thanks to str and mapcat. Takes the input as a list of numbers.

Husk, 8 bytes
=dṁd¹ṁ^3

Try it online!
Takes a list of numbers and outputs 1 (truthy) "if the sum of their cubes is equal to the concatenation of those numbers", otherwise 0 (falsy).
Explanation:
     ṁ^3  # sum up the cubes
  ṁd¹     # split every number into its digits and flatten the list
 d        # join digits back into a single number
=         # check for the equality


AWK, 24 bytes
$0=$1^3+$2^3+$3^3~$1$2$3

awk '$0=$1^3+$2^3+$3^3~$1$2$3' << "1 5 3"

Prints 1 if truthy, or nothing.

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 31 30 bytes
boring wins
s[#.#^2]==s/@#<>""&
s=ToString

Try it online!
